# How to delete a checkbox with a delete button

Tags: javascript, vb.net, button, checkbox, datagrid

I am trying to delete a checkbox with a delete button (Deletebtn) onClick Delete Selected
I have two check boxes a header chkAll and item chkRow in a datagrid table.

```
Sub DeleteSelected(sender as object, e as System.EventArgs)

  Dim item As DataGridItem
  Dim SQLRemoveItem As String

   For Each item In OrderForm.Items


      Dim selection As CheckBox = _
          DirectCast(item.Cells(12).FindControl("chkRow"), CheckBox)

        If  selection IsNot Nothing

        ' AndAlso selection.Checked then

           Dim SQLCheck As String = "select id, isbn from order_detail where ordernumber='{0}' and isbn ='{1}'"
           Dim Check As DataTable = Database.SelectRows(String.Format(SQLCheck, OrderNumber.Text, Item.cells(3).Text))

           SQLRemoveItem = "Delete from order_detail where id = '{0}'" 

           Database.InsertRecord(String.Format(SQLRemoveItem, Check.Rows(0)("id")))

        End if


    Next Item


    BindOrderForm() 'Rebind data after delete

End Sub

 <script type="text/javascript">
$("[id*=chkAll]").live("click", function () {
    var chkAll = $(this);
    var grid = $(this).closest("table");
    $("input[type=checkbox]", grid).each(function () {
        if (chkAll.is(":checked")) {
            $(this).attr("checked", "checked");
            $("td", $(this).closest("tr")).addClass("selected");
        } else {
            $(this).removeAttr("checked");
            $("td", $(this).closest("tr")).removeClass("selected");
        }
    });
});
$("[id*=chkRow]").live("click", function () {
    var grid = $(this).closest("table");
    var chkAll = $("[id*=chkAll]", grid);
    if (!$(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("td", $(this).closest("tr")).removeClass("selected");
        chkAll.removeAttr("checked");
    } else {
        $("td", $(this).closest("tr")).addClass("selected");
        if ($("[id*=chkRow]", grid).length == $("[id*=chkRow]:checked", grid).length) {
            chkAll.attr("checked", "checked");
        }
    }
});
</script>

<asp:TemplateColumn>
<HeaderTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox id="chkAll" runat="server"   />
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox id="chkRow" runat="server" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

My issue, is when I try to search for chkRow and delete the chkrow boxes selected. It deletes everything!

If I should add selection.Checked it does nothing, not sure where I went wrong.
Help please!

Comment: What do you mean it deletes "everything"?

Comment: It deletes all the rows in the data grid, instead of those that are selected.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code and finding out why your jQuery selector is getting all of the rows instead of just the checked ones?

Comment: The JQuery allows ChkAll, to select ChkRow. But the user is then able to select which checkbox in chkRow they want. My problem is that even if the user selects 1 out of 4 checkbox all gets deleted. If I should add selection.checked , the button does nothing.

Comment: I went through the flow and I think its because I didnt bind the checkbox

Comment: When I add <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRow" runat="server" checked='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "id") %>' /> , it selects all the checkbox. However if I don't have it - it selects none!

Answer (score 0):

Your code will delete everything because you loop through all rows, checks if a checkbox exist and then you delete the row. Since you have a checkbox column the checkbox will always be found. I can see your commented line so I understand what you have tried.

This is what I think you should do:

Debug the code and get the value of item.Cells(12). I do believe it should be set to something like "true" or "false". You do not have to typecast the cell to get the value. My bet is that item.Cells(12).ToString() is just about enough to get it.

Then create an appropriate if statement which looks something like this:

```
If item.Cells(12).ToString() = "true"
```